# Can't center text?

Tags: css, html, text, center

I've been trying to center a piece of text on my landing page, by using `top: 50%; left: 50%;` in my html, but for some reason it's not in the center? Here's the html I'm using after the `<body>` tag-

```
<div style="position: absolute; top:50%; left:50%; width:500px; height:25px"><font size="4" color="white">My Text Here</font></div>
```

I don't have any css to go with it apart from the google font css code. (see below)

```
 body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 48px;
  }
```

This is what it's looking like on my website-

http://s11.postimg.org/l1iwonjz7/frigofdhjvuidrh.jpg

P.S I don't have *that* much knowledge of coding so if what I said made no sense, just say.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to negate the margin which is = 1/2 of width and 1/2 of height

Comment: Also, don't use `<font>` tag, it's deprecated

Comment: try add width, and height to your body tag

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/59Cw5/

Comment: Tried that Mr.Tk, didnt work..just made the text dissapear..

Comment: Mr Alien.. say wah? Sorry... like I said I don't have much knowledge on this... is there any chance you could try re writing the coding for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead. Better compatiblity and more robust.

```
<div style="position: absolute; top:50%; width:100%; height:1em; margin-top: -.5em; color: white; font-size: 10px; text-align: center;">My Text Here</div>
```

The above should align the text exactly in the center of the page. The trick is 'text-align: center;'. All child text of a tag will be automatically centered by the browser.

Also, just a note: its usually considered bad practice to use deprecated tags such as the font tag since its results can be achieve using CSS. I refrained from using it and used its general equivalent in CSS.

Comment: Still an tiiiiiiiiinnnnyyyyy bit off to the right! I'm too much of a perfectionist!! Anything I can do just to move it over those few pixels? Apart from that it worked great :-)

Comment: Also, with the css...Is there a code I should add to make it...better?

Comment: Ah I think I see. My guess is that you haven't set the 'body' tag style 'margin: 0;'. By default HTML pages are given a bit of a margin. I just tried that in a test page and got the correct results.

Comment: As for you code, it all looks good to me. Only thing I would say is to separate the CSS code from the HTML tags using the 'style' tags or linking to a CSS file. Nothing wrong with using attributes, just easier to read rule sheets over inline attributes.

Comment: Awesome, all fixed :-) Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code:

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/59Cw5/1/)

```
<div style="position: absolute; top:50%; left:50%; width:500px; height:25px; margin-  left:-250px; margin-top:-13px;background:#ccc;"> 
<font size="4" color="white">My Text Here</font></div>
```

Comment: This just made the text move near the left:/

Comment: Still not working, it's just making the text go close the left :-/

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set:

**text-align:center;**

```
 <div style="position: absolute; top:50%; left:50%; width:500px; height:25px;text-align:center;border:1px solid"><font size="4" color="white">My Text Here</font></div>
```

If this helps you dont forget to accept answer ;)